# How to wait for background jobs to finish in shell

Tags: shell, process, cron

I have this piece of code:

```
sqlplus usr1/pw1@DB1 @$DIR/a.sql $1 &
sqlplus usr2/pw2@DB2 @$DIR/b.sql $1 &
wait
echo "Done!"
```

Both sqlplus sessions in the background so they can run at the same time, and wait command to wait until both of them finish.

In the real program, the "echo" is actually a call to another program that works on spooled files by the previously executed queries, hence the importance to wait for both of them to finish.

I have a problem since it works fine when I execute it by myself, but it doesn't when I schedule it on crontab. Since I can't seem to find the solution, I would like to somehow simulate that behavior. This is my idea:

```
sqlplus usr1/pw1@DB1 @$DIR/a.sql $1
session1=$! //I think this stores sqlpluss pid
sqlplus usr2/pw2@DB2 @$DIR/b.sql $1
session2=$!

while (not finished($session1) and not finished($session2)) //pseudocode
  do nothing //maybe sleep for a few seconds, something that wont waste resources unnecesarally

echo "Done!"
```

I need some help on how to complete that loop. First of all, I'm assuming $session1 and $session2 have the pid of each sqlplus session. Not really sure if that's correct. Then, there must be some easy way of checking if the process is still running, having it's pid. At last, if still either one is running, I want to just wait but not looping millions of times, but maybe sleeping for a minute:

Thanks in advance for any suggestion!

Answer (score 4):

Why can't you use wait in your script when under crontab? In my case, it can.

With a file named 1.sh as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 2>&1
sleep 20&
time wait
echo hello
```

and a task in crontab as below:

```
* * * * * bash ~/1.sh > ~/1.txt
```

It can be shown the wait is working because it cost 20 seconds executing:

```
$cat ~/.logs/1.txt

real    0m20.001s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
hello
```

Now perhaps you can try to debug why wait don't work in your crontab. Are you sure you are using bash instead of another shell like POSIX sh? The behavior can be different.

And if you can't get `wait` working, you can try `flock`.

Comment: +1 for `wait`.  Its also worth nothing that without arguments, `wait` will wait for *all* child background processes.  `man wait` (and then search for it since it's a builtin) has more information.